# GeckoFX DocumentTitle return previous title rather than current

Tags: vb.net, gecko, geckofx

I am having trouble getting the Document Title for a Gecko web browser (1.9.1.2) in Visual Studio 2015 (VB.Net), this is my code, I can get the URL, but the Document Title returns the title of the previous page, not the current one...

```
Private Sub NavFinished(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal g As GeckoNavigatedEventArgs) Handles GeckoWebBrowser.Navigated

alabel.Text =  GeckoWebBrowser.DocumentTitle
anotherlabel.Text = GeckoWebBrowser.Url.ToString

End sub
```

any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around, using GeckoWebBrowser.DocumentTitleChanged - still confused as to why it wouldn't work via navigated tho, if anyone can shed some light on it, that would be great!

Comment: Is NavFinished the 'DocumentCompleted' event handler?

Comment: Perhaps, although I thought "Navigated" was the same thing; perhaps I'm wrong, it seems difficult to find info! For now i'm using DocumentTitleChanged, but that seems to trigger Twice every time a page loads up...I'll give DocumentCompleted a try later